# Layout in html email with JavaMail API

Tags: java, android, html, jakarta-mail

I'm having a hard time trying to compose a great looking (layout wise) html email with JavaMail API.

I know how to add a picture inside the email body, and then add text above and below, but that's kinda it. I'm really hoping to create a little more complex layout with some separators, image borders, larger text titles and so on.

Would I need to know html in order to create this, or does anyone know of a good guide or tutorial on how to work with html JavaMail?

Hope this question isn't to abstract for stackoverflow, thanks.

Comment: Why not using a HTML editor, like office word, or dreamweaver, or frontpage, or ...

Comment: How would i apply this with JavaMail on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a JavaMail problem.

Compose your html however you want.  Then use the MimeBodyPart setText(content, charset, "html") method.