# How to print ArrayList<String> to HTML table for message body using JavaMail API

Tags: java, arraylist, jakarta-mail

I have an ArrayList that reads in lines from a text file and adds these to the ArrayList as below:

```
ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<>();

    // New BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        lineList.add(line);
    }

    // Close it.
    reader.close();
```

I would like to compose an email script using the JavaMail API that wil output the items from the ArrayList in HTML table format.

I haven't posted my entire email script but I understand that I can send HTML by using the following method:

```
message.setContent("", "text/html");
```

How can I achieve looping through the ArrayList printing the lines to a HTML table?

I was thinking something like this:

```
public void createHTMLTable(ArrayList<String> lineList) {
    System.out.println("<table>");
    for (Iterator<String> iter = lineList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println("<tr><td>" + (String) (iter.next()) + "</td></tr>");
    }
    System.out.println("</table>");
}
```

How can I pass that into the message.setContent method?

Comment: You have to create the table and put the contents there.

Comment: That example doesn't explain how you loop through an ArrayList and put that data into the HTML table? I am asking specficially how to do that?

Comment: Yeah, because that's the part where you have to code. Check out how a HTML table is build.

Comment: Hi, please see my edited question. I have produced some code near the bottom. I think I am on the right track? What do you think?

Comment: Learn to do some research before asking people to do your work and your research for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384323/layout-in-html-email-with-javamail-api?rq=1

Comment: I think you guys are being a bit harsh on me. I have even produced some code to get some feedback on. I believe I am close, but just looking for some further insights from those who have experience in this area

Comment: Don't print to System.out, print to a StringWriter, or collect the data in a StringBuilder yourself.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!